# A simple JS-PHP validation (or so I thought)

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong on this? I have seen people use quotes inside the GetElementsByName(), and I have seen people who didn't. The resulting script does nothing when the username is blank.

```
if (document.getElementsByName('username').length < 1) {
        alert("Username must be filled out");
        return false;
     }
```

The call from HTML is this:

```
<form name="stafflogin" action="usermain.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<p>Username:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="15" value=""/>  <br />
Password: <input type="password" id="userpass" name="password" size="15" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value=" - Submit - ">
</p>
```

I know it must be something simple, so forgive me in advance for such foolishness.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it propably would be smarter to use `document.getElementById("username")` instead - this returns a single element and not an array.

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName('username').length < 1` says "if there are no elements in the document named 'username'" -- which will always be false, as there is such an element in the document, and the return value of `getElementsByName` is an array.

What you meant to do instead is

```
if (document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value.length < 1)
```

but I really think it's better (easier to read and harder to mess up) to use

```
if (document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value == "")
```

Since the target element also has an id, it's even better to use `getElementById` which directly returns the element you are looking for (no array to confuse things) and does so faster:

```
if (document.getElementById('username').value == "")
```

Comment: Thank you. That made a great deal of sense - getElementsByName (plural) would refer to an array. I tried the getElementById
`         if (document.getElementById('username')=="") {
            alert("Username must be filled out");

            return false;

         }`
But it still does not work.

Comment: @Chris Wilson you forgot `.value` in if condition.